# Internal compiler error: Bus error with LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler

Tags: gcc, ios4, xcode4, compiler-errors, llvm-gcc

When I am trying to test my application on device with default compiler setting, **LLVM GCC 4.2**, its giving me "**Internal compiler error: Bus error**", but it is working OK with **GCC 4.2** and **LLVM compiler 2.0**.

What can be the possible reason/reasons for this error? Is it possible to distribute your application with GCC 4.2?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using clang?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - sorry, don't know anything about clang with reference to this problem.

Comment: @itsaboutcode Well, clang is a compiler frontend, it is using LLVM as backend. It is a much cleaner combination then LLVM GCC. Try clang and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - In iphone, I have only 3 options - LLVM GCC 4.2, GCC 4.2 and LLVM compiler 2.0.

Comment: @itsaboutcode Oh, ok, then I guess LLVM compiler 2.0 is clang, since LLVM can't compile C by itself, it needs a front-end. OK, so what's wrong with using the LLVM compiler 2.0 option?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - I am not getting any error in this case. But question is, why it is giving me error in default option?

Comment: @itsaboutcode Compilers, as any software, do have bugs. I wouldn't give much thought into it. You can try to isolate the code, that is causing the problem and report the issue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem too, and actually your post kind of solved it -- switching to GCC 4.2 did the trick. I don't know why it failed in the first place (LLVM 2.0 wouldn't work because I am using the TVOutManager library that throws a warning). I also wanted to add that my code compiles fine in the simulator too, regardless of the compiler setting.

Answer (score 0):

"Bus error" usually means  that your application is trying to perform an unaligned memory access, which is not allowed by default.

You can try either tell `gcc` to generate only aligned memory accesses or set the unaligned memory access handling in the OS kernel (not sure whether it's possible in iOS):

```
echo 2 > /proc/cpu/alignment
```

Comment: That's feasible in Linux, but not in OSX / iOS. There's no `/proc` tree on these systems. And `gcc` is no longer the default compiler on iOS, it's `llvm`.